# $10$ men and $7$ women working as supervisors in a company. The company has recently decided to form a committee to represent all the employees….

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> There are $10$ men and $7$ women working as supervisors in a company. The company has recently decided to form a committee to represent all the employees. The committee has to consist of $3$ members, all of whom must be supervisors. The members will be President, General Secretary and Coordinator respectively. Answer the following questions based on this information.

> (a) How many ways can the committee be formed from the supervisors available? 
> (b) How many ways can the committee be formed if the General Secretary must be a female?
> (c) How many ways can the committee be formed if it must have at least one man and at least one woman?

(a) $\binom{17}{3}$ 
(b) $\binom{16}{2}$ 
(c) $\binom{10}{1}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{10}{2} \binom{7}{1}$.

Do you think my answers are correct?

Comment: Please format your questions into logical partitions.

Answer (score 2):

For $(a)$ you have $17\cdot 16\cdot 15=4080$ options.

For $(b)$ you have $7$ options for the General Secretary, times $16\cdot 15=240$, which gives $1680$.

For $(c)$ just multiply your answer by $3!$ to account for the fact that the positions are labeled.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers look mostly correct. There is an easier way to do $(c)$ though. Start by picking a man and a woman. That gives us $\binom{10}{1} \cdot\binom{7}{1} = 70$. We then choose one person out of the $15$ remaining. We then have to permute the members, so we multiply by $3!$. So our answer is $70 \cdot15 \cdot3!$. However, we also have to divide out by $2$ to handle the symmetry cases. So if $m_{1}$ is drawn first and $m_{2}$ is drawn second, the permutations handle the ordering of those.

Note- for all of your answers, since the committees have labeled positions, you have to permute the members through the positions. So you have to multiply by $3!$ for each of your solutions.

Comment: Well, I see how your approach to (c) is a whole lot easier. But, it turns out it returns an answer that's double of mine. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you revise your answer to permute the elements? Your answer for (c) isn't handling ordering.

Comment: I understand that I do have to permute the elements, but assuming for the moment that the question has three equal committee members, my answer and yours still don't match. I have $\binom{10}{1}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{10}{2} \binom{7}{1}$ whereas you have (70)(15). That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: I forgot to divide out by $2$ so I don't count permutations of members of a single group twice. I've updated my answer, and I apologize for any confusion I may have caused.